# Workflow Foundation 4 Designer Performance Issue

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a large visual studio solution with hundreds of projects and a pretty large domain model (thousands of classes in the object graph).

My goal was to move some business logic to a windows workflow, and i have accomplished to build a workflow with the following features:

- less than 50 WF activities in a FlowChart (if, Sequences, Assign, ForEach, AddToCollection..)
- 10-15 In-Out arguments of custom types from referenced assemblies
- 5-6 Variables of custom types from referenced assemblies
- Added all the used assemblies to the Imports tab and to the project references of the activity library. All the imports look fine to me.

However, i have HUGE workflow designer performance issues. When i open the workflow designer in visual studio 2010, it takes between 10 and 20 minutes to load!? It loads first the outer activities, and then it loads the inner (nested) activities one by one, and each one takes from 15 seconds to a couple of minutes. It looks like some heavy processing is happening since the processor utilization is at 80%!

Does anybody know what is the cause of this slowness and how to resolve this issue?..

Thanks

Comment: I got an answer on MSDN forums. It looks like it was caused by the resharper plugin. Once i disabled it it started working normally.